# How to write the aggregation query in Java for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation

I has to join the two tables in Mongbd Based on the Object id and get the result. One table contains employee details other table contains employee image
I had database name as EmployeeData
I had two collection named as :employe contains employee information.
and photo.files contains image.(using GridFS employee image is inserted into DB)

In Mongo shell bellow query giving join result

```
db.employee.aggregate([
   {$match: {"_id" : ObjectId("5c9c37df3aa2359d6b998e18")}},
   {$lookup: {
     from: "photo.files",
     localField: "_id",
     foreignField: "_id",
     as: "test"
     }}
    ]);
```

result as:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9c37df3aa2359d6b998e18"), "name" : "Ramoji Rao Y", "age" : 28, "experiecne" : 3, "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-03-28T02:56:31.752Z"), "test" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5c9c37df3aa2359d6b998e18"), "filename" : "ramoji-test-image", "aliases" : null, "chunkSize" : NumberLong(262144), "uploadDate" : ISODate("2019-03-28T08:47:16.531Z"), "length" : NumberLong(46178), "contentType" : null, "md5" : "3aca3ecc2dd5ba3a138ce76362586ee1" } ] }

Now I want above query in Java Can any one help me how to write using aggregation.

Or any other simple way to implement in java.

I had implemented as per the suggestion given by Yohanaa
the code is

```
package Mongo_aggregate;

import com.mongodb.Block;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Projections;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFS;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile;
import com.sun.prism.Image;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.text.html.ImageView;

import org.bson.Document;

public class Imgae_featch {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
         Block<Document> printBlock = new Block<Document>(){
                public void apply(final Document document) {
                    System.out.println("Test Ramoji");
                    System.out.println(document.toJson().length());
                }
            };
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("EmployeeData");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("employee");

        System.out.println("colletion data before is:" +collection);
        collection.aggregate(
                   Arrays.asList(
                     Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("_id", "5c9c37df3aa2359d6b998e18")),
                     Aggregates.lookup("$photo.files", "_id", "_id", "test")

                   )

                ).forEach(printBlock);

    }

}
```

Not producing any result can you help on it.

Comment: have you looked into this? Link: https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/query-code/#mongodb-to-java-3-x-driver-api

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Mongo Java Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/driver/tutorials/aggregation/) with the [lookup](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/builders/aggregation/#lookup) aggregation.
Something like this:

```
    collection.aggregate(
       Arrays.asList(
         Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("_id", "5c9c37df3aa2359d6b998e18")),
         Aggregates.lookup("$photo.files", "_id", "_id", "test")
       )
    ).forEach(printBlock);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply but it did work well.